# How do I match a word if it starts with a nonalphanumeric character in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a text file where each line contains either '1' or '-1.' How do I search through the file to check if the file contains at least one '1'?

Initially, I had the following.

```
if re.search(r'\b1', f.read()): return true
else: return false
```

However, this does not work because '-' is not considered an alphanumeric string and returns true if the file does not contain a single '1.' What is the best way to determine if the file contains '1'?

Comment: Is there a typo in the first para? Each line contains "1" or "-1", but you want to check if the *file* contains "1" or "-1"??? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: if "1" in f.read(): print "There Is a 1!!!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`re.MULTILINE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag, `^` will match start of lines (instead of only start of subject):

```
re.search(re.compile('^1', re.MULTILINE), f.read())
```

This will match if any line starts with `1`.

See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

---

This alternative solution avoid reading the file entirely:

```
has_1 = any(line == "1" for line in f)
```

Comment: I think you'll have to strip off the EOL markers or the `==` won't be true in general.

Comment: Which method do you think is faster?

Answer (score 1):

`any('1' in line for line in file)` is one way without reading the entire file to memory.

**A convoluted but possibly efficient way**

```
fmap = mmap.mmap(open('file').fileno(), 0)
'1' in fmap
```

You can also run a re against the mmap'd file.

```
re.search('^1', fmap, re.M)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open("textfile.txt", "rb")
lines = f.readlines()
new_lines = [line.replace("-1", "") for line in lines]
for line in new_lines:
    if "1" in line:
        print "Damn right!"
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def thingy(contents):
    return any(line.strip() == "1" for line in contents.splitlines())

thingy("1\n-1\n-1") # True
thingy("-1\n-1\n-1") # False
```

Alternatively:

```
def thingy(contents):
    for line in contents.splitlines():
        if line.strip() == "1":
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: I need to check if at least one '1' exists in the file. This returns true if '-1' does not exist which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Simply with list comprehension :

```
>>> if not None in [ re.search( r"1", line ) for line in f.readlines() ] :
        pass # <your code here>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the '1' or '-1' always occurs at the start of the line, then you could change the regex to:

```
 ^1
```

If they always occur in the middle/end of the line, then use:

```
[^-]1
```

If they sometimes occur at the start and sometimes in the middle/end, then you might try something like:

```
^1|[^-]1
```

I haven't tested these. The last one, in particular, I'm not sure if the precedence is right.